# SQL SELECT Query Performance between AND and Interlaced SELECT´s

Tags: sql, postgresql

Good evening. I am new to SQL and I am currently learning how to write SQL SELECT statements. I read a lot about the difference of performance between different ways of writing SELECT statement.

I am asking myself about the difference between one SELECT query with a lot AND statements and "Interlaced" SELECT statements.

e.g

```
SELECT s.name
FROM studenten s, vorlesungen v, hoeren h, professoren p
WHERE p.name='Kant'
    AND s.matr_nr=h.matr_nr
    AND v.vorl_nr=h.vorl_nr
    AND v.gelesen_von=p.pers_nr;
```

```
SELECT s.name FROM studenten s, 
    (SELECT h.matr_nr FROM hoeren h , 
        (SELECT v.vorl_nr FROM Vorlesungen v, 
            (SELECT p.pers_nr FROM Professoren p WHERE name ='Kant') AS tab1 
        WHERE tab1.pers_nr = v.gelesen_von) AS tab2 
    WHERE tab2.vorl_nr=h.vorl_nr) AS tab3 
WHERE tab3.matr_nr=s.matr_nr;
```

Which is better. Or is there maybe a third even better way?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: I'll read it over. Thanks :)

Comment: .... and your 2020 resolution should be to **start using it** from this day on, and never go back!

Comment: Hi k1moj, from my point of view, you always go for the simplest way of scripting, (unless you have performance improvement reasons to go for complications). Simplicity shows that you care about the next guy who will take over or support your code.

Comment: i promise :) @marc_s

Comment: There is no difference at all. If you want proof, check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT s.name
FROM studenten s
JOIN hoeren h USING (matr_nr)
JOIN vorlesungen v USING (vorl_nr)
JOIN professoren p ON (v.gelesen_von = p.pers_nr)
WHERE p.name='Kant';
```

Note that with `USING`, you don't really need the table aliases for `hoeren` or `vorlesungen`. You only need aliases to distinguish between `studenten.name` and `professoren.name`. Hence, the query could be shortened to

```sql
SELECT s.name
FROM studenten s
JOIN hoeren USING (matr_nr)
JOIN vorlesungen USING (vorl_nr)
JOIN professoren p ON (gelesen_von = p.pers_nr)
WHERE p.name='Kant';
```

Whether you want to keep the table aliases or not is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

Just use table joins:

```
SELECT s.name
FROM studenten s, 
JOIN hoeren h ON s.matr_nr=h.matr_nr
JOIN vorlesungen v ON v.vorl_nr=h.vorl_nr
JOIN professoren p ON v.gelesen_von=p.pers_nr
WHERE p.name='Kant';
```